# OpenCV: cvtColor function cause error on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm running an [OpenCV code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kylehounslow/opencv-tuts/master/object-tracking-tut/objectTrackingTut.cpp) on my laptop both on Windows using Visual Studio and Ubuntu VM (using CMake). The code works perfectly fine on both but when I try to run it on my Raspberry Pi 2B, the function `cvtColor()` (line 205), cause the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/Track1 $ ./TrackObj 
init done 
opengl support available 
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor, file /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3961
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3961: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cvtColor

Aborted
```

I've seen recommendations to try to check if the frame is empty but I'm not sure how to do it in [this code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kylehounslow/opencv-tuts/master/object-tracking-tut/objectTrackingTut.cpp) given the fact that it is not running.

I've also tried to change the input from `camera.open(0);` to `camera.open("someMovieInFolder.mp4");` but the problem stays as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. Indeed the problem was with the image being empty, that's what caused the run-time error. **The reason was the Pi camera**. Unfortunately this function does not work with the Pi cam (or at least some adjustments needed) so after plunging a USB camera it all worked perfectly.

Comment: I got mine to work by installing V4L drivers available [here](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14).

Answer (score 2):

It looks indeed as if the image was empty. The image capture function [returns a boolean value](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=capture#bool%20VideoCapture::read(Mat&%20image)) that can be checked to see if the capture was completed successfully and returned a vaild image. You could also try to printf or cout the width/height of the image. It should be non-zero.